# Output all documents in a nested collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to have all the documents in a collection printed out to me. However, the following code is not executed or I cannot get into the forEach loop. I have a nested collection in Firestore.
users//entries/uuid()/doc

[image]

```
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "eintraege"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // Never executed
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop is not executed because you're using an incomplete reference. If you want to query the `eintraege` subcollection, then you have to use the following reference:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "benj...@gmx.de" "eintraege"));
```

Where `users` is the top-level collection, `"benj...@gmx.de"` is the ID of the document, and `eintraege` is the subcollection.